# VB6 Math.Random to C# Code

Tags: c#, random, vb6

So I have the following code in VB6

```
string CharString = "KO0LPBGt7HU8NJI9acfDXESvgbYujmikolpw3MZWAQyhn6TFCR1q2Vzse4xdr5";

string DatePassword = string.Empty; 

float x = VBMath.Rnd(-1);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

x = VBMath.Rnd(-1);
VBMath.Randomize(dt.ToOADate());

for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
   double y = Math.Truncate(VBMath.Rnd()*62);
   DatePassword += CharString.Substring( Convert.ToInt32(y), 1);
}
```

I am having trouble converting this code over to C#. In particular how call randomize with the seed being a double. Here is my attempt in C#

```
string CharString = "KO0LPBGt7HU8NJI9acfDXESvgbYujmikolpw3MZWAQyhn6TFCR1q2Vzse4xdr5";

string DatePassword = string.Empty;

Random rnd = new Random(-1);
float x = rnd.Next();

DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + 1);

x = rnd.Next();
double z = rnd.NextDouble() * dt.ToOADate();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    x = rnd.Next();
    double y = Math.Truncate(x * 62);
    DatePassword += CharString.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(y), 1);
}
```

Comment: What's your error ?

Comment: If your existing VB6 code works, it might be useful to include it.

Comment: Why would you need to seed Random with a double ? All you need to ensure is that the seed value differs everytime you call Random(seed). If you want to use the DateTime object, then take a look at DateTime.Now.Ticks which returns a long  ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: Besides the random being very weird, you are also declaring your DateTime incorrectly. Instead of DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + 1) maybe try DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)

Comment: @Rahul, the first block of code is not VB!

Comment: @mjwills I need to create a random code from the string based on the date in C# but the random code must be the exact same as the one that is generated in the VB6 code

Comment: What's the reason for all this `DateTime` stuff? Doesn't this basically boil down to calling `CharString[rnd.Next(CharString.Length)]` six times?

Comment: @mjwills because I must replicate this part of the VB tool in a different C# tool

Comment: @JohnSmitty - the implementation of the `random` functionality is not guaranteed to be the same. Actually I'd be very surprised if it was. So you'll never get "the exact same" values. -- basically: why change a running system?

Comment: @Corak I don't have any experience in VB but I have used the VB tool and it generates a random code based on the date and it works consistently based on the date

Comment: @JohnSmitty - You can also consistently generate a random code based on the date with C# `Random`, but I highly doubt it would be always the same as when using `VBMath.Rnd`. Because both PRNGs very probably work with different algorithms internally. So even if you manage to get "equal" seeds based on the date, the very next "random" number is probably vastly different between the two.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. it doesn't look like VB.Net either. It looks like C# or maybe even C++ code which uses the `VBMath` library, so the question seems to be how to take odd-looking C# code which uses a VB6 library and replace it by equivalent C# code which doesn't.

Comment: You seem to have your code snippets listed backwared.  Also neither of the code snippets you supplied is VB6.